# Javascript how to ascertain if it is a comma delimited list?

Tags: javascript

I'm curious, how would you test a string and say "yep, that is a comma delimited list!"  I'm not so worried about the 'comma delimited' part more that this string has more than one item in it?

Thanks, R.

Comment: Are you trying to determine the difference from a string that is a probable csv and one that is a probably sentence?  If so, the answer may be much more complicated than merely checking for one or more commas.

Comment: No, its not a sentence, but a list of items concatenated together, depending on a particular set of circumstances.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about:

```
stringObject.indexOf(",") >= 0
```

Comment: Whilst this will ensure the string will parse as a CSV, to determine if it *should* be is another story.

Answer (score 4):

To check if the string has more than one item, try something like:

```
str.split(",").length > 1
```

... although, as suggested in a comment, correct parsing is likely to be bit more complicated than this for the general case.

#### Edit:

whoops, misread language as Java - sorry.

Comment: Why are Java CSV parsers going to help in JavaScript? They're completely different languages.

Answer (score 1):

Be very careful if you are just splitting on a comma for a csv list as fields can actually contain commas and are encased by quotes i.e.
Name,Age
"doe, jane",18
"bob, jim",20

If it isn't for a csv perhaps you should be using an array or an object to hold the values?

Comment: Thanks, as alex said very useful advice.  The only thing I can say in my defence is that I know that there will only be one item in the list (so its not really a list, just one item!) unless it comes from a particular source, in which case then it is something else, which I want to catch.  Sounds odd I know, but that's the way its designed...

Not my code, just trying to make it work.

Comment: Do you have some sample data of what you'll be expecting? Will it just be a bunch of numbers or more csv like?

Answer (score 0):

You could also just go like:

```
var words = yourString.split(',');
for(var i=0;i<words.length;++i) {
  doSomething(words[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
(string.split(",").length > 1)
```

Steve